# RESTful trailing slash routes in laravel

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I have the following routes in my Laravel 3 RESTful api project

```
Route::delete('/(:any)', 'resources@destroy');

Route::delete('users/(:any)', 'users@destroy');
```

The problem I am having is when a user sends a delete request to /users/

What I want to happen is that the `users@destroy` route is called with parameter `null`. In my controller I have an exception for a user trying to delete a `null` resource.

What seems to be happening is that the `resource@destroy` route is called with parameter `users`. This obviously has the undesired affect of deleting the users resource.

I know I could modify my .htaccess but technically /users/ does belong to the users controller not the resources controller. I want to maintain that relationship.

I was wondering if there is a simple  way to solve this from within Laravel?

EDIT: have the above working with the answer below. Now I have an error in my get routes

```
Route::get('users/(:any?)', 'users@show');
Route::get('users', 'users@index');
```

/users and /users/ both call users@index which I don't want.

I need GET /users to go to users@index and GET /users/ to go to users@show with null parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around the trailing slash by adding a filter to my routes

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'trailingslash'), function()
{
   //routes in here
});

Route::filter('trailingslash', function() {
    $current = URI::full();
    if(substr($current, -1) == '/'){
        return return Response::error('404');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

one point you need to consider.

> Routes are defined without a front-slash. The only exception to this is the default route which is represented with only a front-slash.

so `Route::delete('/(:any)', 'resources@destroy')` will cause undesired result.

Moreover, your order is wrong.

`(:any)` will match `user` too and will send the request to `resources` controller.

so what you need to do is,

- change the order (make it reverse).
- change the route of `resources` considering according to the rules. like `resources/delete` etc.....

> *What I want to happen is that the users@destroy route is called with parameter null. In my controller I have an exception for a user trying to delete a null resource.*

to do this, (after making the changes above....)

change the route of `user/(:any)` to `user/(:any?)` which will make the 2nd segment optional.

After that, straight forward.

```
$foo = URI::segment(2, null);
//Rest will follow.
```

### EDIT

Now, the following code,

```
Route::get('users/(:any?)', 'users@show');
Route::get('users', 'users@index');
```

does not make any sense.

if i type `user`, what the router is suppose to take?

`user@show` with no optional segment or `user@index`?

Routes are design so that it removes the ambiguity. You are going in the opposite direction with making it all ambiguity.

just make a simple route.

like show

```
  user/show
```

*delete*

```
  user/delete
```

*edit*

```
  user/edit
```

etc....

The type of routing you are applying is confusing for both users and developers as it carries ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks. Delete routing is working great now. I do have another issue now. Have updated question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I can see your point, but I can't implement your solution as I am trying to build a RESTful API. user/delete, user/edit violate REST. I have to be able to use DELETE user, PUT user. Do you know another way to have GET users and GET users/ go to different routes?

Comment: both are in same method. So only one will run. The other will never get trigger.

Comment: yes i know. I want to know is there a way to get them to trigger by some other means? I need someway of getting laravel to recognise null after a /